# Problems connecting Qt 4.7.3 with VisualStudio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt

I dont know how to integrate Qt with Visual Studio 2008. I just installed it and followed a tutorial on this link http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/install-win.html but i get this error in the Visual Studio Command Prompt :

"Building qmake failed, return code 2"

you can read the entire log here http://pastebin.com/qPjUQxaQ

Comment: You should paste any error messages into your question and format them to be readable. If the log file is very long, try to trim it down to the essentials. If anyone thinks there may be important information not included, they will ask you for it. Most will not bother with the download annoyances of hotfile and other file hosting services like it.

Comment: I have changed the host for the logfile to pastebin so it's accessible to all. You might want to do something similar next time or people are unlikely to read it, as Arnold says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure tells you:

> All the required DirectShow/Direct3D
>   files couldn't be found. Make sure you
>   have either the platform SDK AND the
>   DirectShow SDK or the Windows  SDK
>   installed. If you have the DirectShow
>   SDK installed, please make sure that
>   you have run the  \SetEnv.Cmd script.

Did you do this? And make sure to use a Visual Studio Command Shell to run configure and nmake.